# Hover works only on one element

Tags: javascript, hover, jsfiddle

I'm using JavaScript and trying to show every elements information on mouse hover. So far I get only first elements information, the second isn't active. How to get working all elements?

Here is JavaScript code:

```
$('#user').hover(function() {
    $('#popup').show();
}, function() {
    $('#popup').hide();
});
```

```
<div id='user'>I am a user. Move your mouse over me</div>
<div id='popup'>Extended info about a user</div>
<div id='user'>I am a user. Move your mouse over me</div>

<div>I a piece of useless information. No use hovering over me.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hyw7Z/1/

Comment: your markup is inconsistent, you can't have two or more elements with the same id at one page

Comment: Carry this with you at all times: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the same value for "id" on more than one element without things like this happening. Instead, use "class"

```
<div class="user" ... >
```

Then, in JavaScript:

```
$('.user').hover(function() { ...
```

Same goes for "popup", but for that you'll want something like this:

```
$('.user').hover(function() {
  $(this).next('.popup').show();
}, function() {
  $(this).next('.popup').hide();
});
```

That'll find the next element after the hovered `<div>` that's got class "popup", and show/hide it.  If there's no such element, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an ID selector. ID's are only allowed to be placed once on a page. You can use a class selector for this.

```
<div class='user'>I am a user. Move your mouse over me</div>
<div id='popup'>Extended info about a user</div>
<div class='user'>I am a user. Move your mouse over me</div>

$('.user').hover(function() {
    $('#popup').show();
}, function() {
    $('#popup').hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hyw7Z/2/).